# Probability Question About Basketball Free Throws and Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I was trying to solve the following question from the Harvard Stat $110$ course, from the book Introduction to Probability by Blitzstein and Hwang, but could not wrap my head around it. Any and all help is appreciated, especially with part (b):

> A certain basketball player practices shooting free throws over and over
>   again. The shots are independent, with probability p of success.
>
> - **(a)** In $n$ shots, what is the expected number of streaks of $7$ consecutive successful shots?
>     (Note that, for example, $9$ in a row counts as $3$ streaks.)
> - **(b)** Now suppose that the player keeps shooting until making $7$ shots in a row for the first time. Let $X$ be the number of shots taken. Show that $E(X) ≤ 7/p^7.$

**Hint:** Consider the first $7$ trials as a block, then the next $7$ as a block, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your explanation on (a), but here's my take on (b):

Let $E(n)$ be the expected number of shots taken until $n$ shots are made in a row. We have the following recursive relationship:
$$E(n) = E(n-1) + p + (1-p)(1+E(n)).$$
Simplifying this, we get:
$$E(n) = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{E(n-1)}{p}$$
Knowing $E(0) = 0$, we can prove that $E(7) = \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^3}+\frac{1}{p^4}+\frac{1}{p^5}+\frac{1}{p^6}+\frac{1}{p^7}\leq \frac{7}{p^7}.$

Answer (score 0):

(b) has already been answered very well, so here is my take on (a):

Let us use linearity of expected value.

Let $I_n$ denote a random variable such that $I_n=1$ if and only if the $n$-th shot was the end of a streak ($I_n=0$ for $n<7$).

Then the requiered expected value $E(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[I_n]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P[I_n=1]=\sum\limits_{i=7}^n p^7=(n-6)p^7$